# Vaadin Viritin SubSetSelector component - change the remove button description

Tags: java, vaadin

I use viritin's SubSetSelector. 
I can not change the description("Removes the selection from the list") of the remove button. How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that extends `SubSetSelector` and use that class in your code instead of `SubSetSelector`.

```
public class MySubSetSelector<ET> extends SubSetSelector<ET> {

    public MySubSetSelector(Class<ET> elementType) {
        super(elementType);
    }

    protected Object getToolColumnContent(final ET entity) {
        Button button = new Button(FontAwesome.MINUS);
        button.setDescription("Removes the selection from the list"); // Change this
        button.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_ICON_ONLY);
        button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                removeSelectedOption(entity);
            }
        });
        button.setStyleName(Reindeer.BUTTON_SMALL);
        return button;
    }
}
```